# iOS App Suspended Automatically After around a Day (or two)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios12

My iOS 12 app that runs a SceneKit session will go into the background on it's own after 24-48 hours. I'm running on a 10.5" iPad Pro and using about 800MB of memory. The device's display is set to never go to sleep. I have Crashlytics running, and so far have no reported bugs.

Any pointers on what could be the issue?

Comment: Hi Tony, did you try to reproduce the issue with a debug session in order to get more information ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. It's too long of a session to leave attached to my machine. I might have to do a dedicated setup for this, though.

Answer (score 1):

It was in fact a tiny memory leak that shut down the app after a long period of time. Memory profiler did the trick. Still undetermined why Crashlytics did not pick up the crash.